# aframe - how to get rid of the VR button

Tags: aframe

Hello I was wondering how can i get rid of the VR button in the aframe and replace it with another link button please? I have looked all over and i can not find where it is located. I have tried the code `<a-scene vr-mode-ui="enabled: false"></a-scene>` but it is still there.

Joseph

Answer (score 0):

Helloi figure it out. I had the code in the wrong place. I should of put it in the begining  of the body and what i did was put it in the middle of the body code and that is why it wasn't working.